# Cannot save another row after 158 rows in Custom Field Suite plugin loop in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I been using custom field suite for creating a custom field in WordPress. Unfortunately after having 158 rows in CFS loop it cannot save the next added rows. Is this a problem on the plugin or it could be the maximum size limit issue of an array?

Thanks for Helping.

Comment: Already solve this. Just increase the max_input_vars of the php.